# Note-taking app with Markdown & code snippets (Web app or OS X)

Tags: note-taking, markdown

Besides [Quiver](http://happenapps.com), is there any other OS X or Web-based note-taking app that has:

- Full Markdown support, including the ability **to write and render code snippets**.
- List view to browse the notes.
- Does have the usual stuff like tags & search.

(Quiver by the way supports code snippets, but it's doesn't use the Markdown syntax for that, so sadly it's not good for me.)

Answer (score 3):

You could look at doing your note taking using [iPython](http://ipython.org/)/[Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) Notebooks.

- Full Markdown Support in several flavours
- MathJax for equations.
- HTML support
- Not quite WYSIWYG but as soon as you move on to the next cell the cell that you have been working on is rendered.
- Embed local or remote files
- Code snippets in hundreds of programming languages with full syntax highlighting
- Can also embed data from the web
- Can generate charts, (including based on live web data)
- Code only cells can also be executed and the resulting output displayed in multiple programming languages, *(depending what you have installed)*, including python *(default)*, Julia, R, Bash, Haskell, Ruby, Perl.
- Save to ipython notebooks and export to Markdown, HTML, reST or pdf.
- Automatically saves your work in progress every few minutes
- Allows reverting to specific checkpoint.
- Free - gratis & open source
- Runs on multiple platforms including OS-X, Windows, Linux

An example showing some of the features:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown Notes](http://markdownnotes.com) would be a good contender here. It has markdown, code highlighting and live preview, among other things.

There's a live demo on the front page.